sample from isotropic Gaussian distribution on SO(3) group
Sampling from the isotropic Gaussian distribution on SO(3) group has been applied in many machine learning models such as diffusion models. A common way to do the sampling is: first uniformly sample an axis (unit vector), and then sample a rotation angle $w\in [0,\pi]$ with some special density $f(w)$. However, I find that in different papers, the forms of $f(w)$ are different.
In https://openreview.net/forum?id=BY88eBbkpe5,
$$f(w)=\frac{1-\cos(w)}{\pi}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(2l+1)e^{-l(l+1)\epsilon^2}\frac{\sin((l+1/2)w)}{\sin(w/2)}$$ where $\epsilon^2$ represents the variance.
In https://openreview.net/forum?id=kKF8_K-mBbS,
$$f(w)=\frac{1-\cos(w)}{\pi}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(2l+1)e^{-l(l+1)\epsilon^2/2}\frac{\sin((l+1/2)w)}{\sin(w/2)}$$ Now there is $/2$ in the exp term.
In https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.02277,
$$f(w)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(2l+1)e^{-l(l+1)\epsilon^2/2}\frac{\sin((l+1/2)w)}{\sin(w/2)}$$ There is no factor $\frac{1-\cos(w)}{\pi}$.
I don't know which one is correct and I am curious why they are different.
Thanks!
